# New activity or new fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

It seems like there are two options when you want to show the user a new screen:

1. Start a new activity (i.e. `startActivity(Intent)`)
2. Swap fragments (i.e. `FragmentTransaction`)

What is the difference?  Which one should be used?

---

**Example**

I want the user to be able to navigate between 3 screens.  Each one is in a fragment.  I can use ...

1. 3 single-fragment activities.
2. 1 activity, which dynamically switches fragments.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views

Comment: Fragments are used within an activity. Do a little more research on: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 2):

An activity is a higher-level UI element that often contains fragments. If you are using fragmentTransaction, then you would be swapping fragments *within* an activity. A whole new activity would be if you were switching to a functionally separate section of your app, for example.

check out these for reference:
[Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html),
[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)