# Android: How to completely remove ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

How can I completely remove the ActionBar from Certain Fragments. I want to remove it not just to hide it. I have Actionbar Tab Navigation. From that i added a new Fragmnt which didn't need actionBar. So i need to remove it. I can't hide it because when i pressed back button and moved to Tabs section, i need to show Action bar again.

This is how i am replacing Fragments.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: dude, drop the nested fragments. I refuse to help whilst you hold fragments at ransom.

Comment: @Blundell i have added some code and explanation Please have look.

Answer (score 0):

The action bar is not part of your fragment. It's part of your `activity`.

You can create a new Activity with a theme `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` and open this Activity with :

```
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class));
```

And inside your second activity you can display the fragment you want.
I recommend you this post to understand more the differences between Fragment and Activity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10515807/3112836

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using `actionbar.hide()` just because you have to show Action bar in other fragment, than I think you should give it a try by using :
`actionbar.hide()` inside `onAttach` method of your fragment and `actionBar.show()` inside your `onDestroy()` method.