# Does Activity and Fragment construct circular reference?

Tags: java, c#, android, garbage-collection, xamarin.android

I read a few articles on avoiding circular references this morning. And I just realized that in Android, if an Activity contains a Fragment, that Fragment should also hold a reference to the containing Activity. Isn't it setting up a circular reference?

I feel this might be a silly question, but asking silly questions is a good way to learn, isn't it?

Comment: There are no stupid questions, only stupid people, who don't ask.

Answer (score 0):

The activity and Fragment has there own life cycles, there is no circular reference thing ,try to make your hands dirty with different Fragment and Activity Life cycles , you will come to know.

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful discussion on the [difference between Activity and Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822656/what-are-the-differences-between-activity-and-fragment) which sheds some more light. The relationship between Activity and Fragment is such that a "Fragment" represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. An Activity may contain 0 or multiple number of fragments (usually in two-pane views or Tablet UIs).
You can read more on the subject from the official documentation  [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

yes it's a circular reference but one that android manages by detaching the fragment from its host (therefore breaking the circular reference) before destroying, garbage collection can then occur.