# Android UI: Most efficient way to have multiple elements in a single activity

Tags: android, xml, performance, user-interface, memory-efficient

In an Android application I'm building, I have a single activity which has multiple buttons and textviews. Based on user actions, I hide the elements and/or show them. This is intentional, cause I don't want the user to change activity.

For further clarity, the activity is a type controller. So when a user enables an option different buttons show up. This is why I want all of them in the same activity.

I am concerned about performance. Currently everything is in a Constraint Layout. Is there an effective way of having mutliple UI elements in the same activity, and having the ability to hide and show them at will? Should I look into Fragments?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822656/what-are-the-differences-between-activity-and-fragment

Comment: @JaiminModi Thank you for the link, I will study more about Fragments

Comment: Reading your requirement, I don't think `Fragment` fits your need. `Fragment` intents to contain a meaning section of an activity, it has its own job and can interact with others, like LoginFragment, ProfileFragment... You only want to show/hide some views within the activity base on interaction. Wrap your views that need to show/hide inside `ViewFlipper` instead. it's small, easy to use with small case like this.

Comment: @GeneralNfG Fragments can be used with ViewPager, ViewFlipper, NavigationDrawer, and if there any special requirement to show and update specific part on single screen. I don't think that you should use Fragment for such thing you asked.

Comment: I looked into your suggestions and posted my conclusion as an answer. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there isn't a clear answer.

There are a few solutions that may prove useful, I list them below for anyone who might stumble onto this:

- `Fragment` is useful when you have multiple independent parts of your layout. You are limited in the communication between elements of different `Fragments`.
- `ViewStub` is used when you have some elements which are rarely used in your layout. This makes the initial loading of the layout lighter by not inflating the elements in the `ViewStub`. You can then inflate the elements on demand.
- `ViewFlipper` allows you to cycle through a list of elements (or display them selectively using `setDisplayedChild`). It's mostly used for single elements, so I'm not sure about its performance if you were to use it for showing and hiding nested layouts.
- `ConstraintLayout` is probably the best solution for cases similar to mine, where you have a layout of buttons and text which are hidden and displayed in a complex manner.