# How to navigate from one activity to a fragment of another activity in android studio?

Tags: android

I am getting an error

```
 public void on_Image_Button_9_Clicked(View view)
    {
        Intent click 5=new Intent(home.this,category 2.class);
        start Activity(click 5);
    }
```

// category 2 is fragment

Comment: What error are you getting? This guide may help in writing your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you did not understand the point of Activities and Fragments. You should take a look at the documentation. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments. You can also take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25822815/3780625

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. To access a fragment you need to create a FragmentTransaction.

I invite you to read this guide on [how fragments work](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#java) to prevent any bad habits using it.

So, either you call your activity containing the fragment you want or you load the fragment in your current container.

To add a fragment to an activity you can declare it in you activity's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or add a container to your activity and display your fragment inside the container using a FragmentTransaction:

myActivity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/myContainer"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

myActivity.java

```
 public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.myActivity_layout);
            setFragment()
        }


        public void setFragment() {
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment, and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.myContainer, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```