# Why use fragments in navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I followed this tutorial about navigation drawer [androidhive-navigation drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) and it has used fragments for the list items.

Similarly all sources I found use fragment views for individual list items. I have these issues.

1. Why use fragments, when we can use an ordinary Activity class?
2. Going with the link example, if I have Home Activity class implemented before, what should I do to convert it to a fragment?
3. If Home is the main activity, what happens then?

Comment: Because [Fragments are overrated](http://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html).

Comment: Take a look at those 2:  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306091/dilemma-when-to-use-fragments-vs-activities).