# ANDROID : embed an activity in another activity

Tags: android-activity

I have an activity where the game is running , for the add on purposes of the game like score,level logo etc.. i need to embed this activity in another activity or any other approach to achieve this ?

The following image clears my view of need,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaKy3.png

Comment: show what u have tried.

Comment: so far i have developed my game play area, and i'm stuck to use which layout or which sort.. to proceed further !

Comment: try somethin.Use google.If any error or prob arise then ask here.No one's gonna write code for u .So try something that's how u learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it and I thought I would give an answer for anyone else who happens to come across this in the future.

A good way to organize different pieces of one screen in your app is to use fragments instead of activities. Here are some links that will describe this in more detail for you:

## Android documentation:

[Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

## Fragments vs. Activities on Stack Overflow

[Android - I need some clarifications of fragments vs activities and views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-i-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views)

[Dilemma: when to use Fragments vs Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306091/dilemma-when-to-use-fragments-vs-activities)