# Connecting to Google Play game services for all activities within a project

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, google-play-services, android-fragmentactivity

Based on the Google Play game services samples, particularly TypeANumber, from (https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples), I was wondering if it's preferred to implement all of the activities as **fragments** (other than MainActivity that's responsible for instantiating and connecting to GoogleApiClient) if I wanted my app to be connected to the services the whole time.

Because, I already developed a game app that consists of activities that transitions to each other by using using Bundles and Intents, and now I am just starting to figure out how to implement Google Play game services to my game. I already read the tutorials and whatnot, but I just want to know if it's recommended to use fragments for the other activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you're pretty much just asking which is better to use between `Activity` and `Fragment`. It technically still depends on you are aiming for. Looked around the community for a while and found these posts where the answers are very much detailed:

[Dilemma: when to use Fragments vs Activities:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306091/dilemma-when-to-use-fragments-vs-activities)

[Why fragments, and when to use fragments instead of activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-i-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views)

On a simpler note, I prefer to use `Fragment` when re-usability is needed.