# Set Relative Layout background image using an imageView in android

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

i have a relative layout and an imageView i want to set the relative layout background image through the imageView image ressource , this is the code  :

```
 ImageView iv = new ImageView(null) ;
   Picasso.get().load("http://10.0.2.2:3000/uploads/"+imgtrip+".png").into(iv); 
   viewHolder.rltvLayout.setBackground(iv.getDrawable);
```

i am getting this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

in this line :

```
  ImageView iv = new ImageView(null) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageView` constructor requires a `Context` parameter.

If this code is in your activity, pass `this`, or `getActivity()` from a fragment, or pass the activity into the adapter's constructor if it is a listview/recyclerview adapter and use that in the view holder, etc.

In your case, in your adapter,

```
class MyAdapter extends ListAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    // ...

    // in where you use ImageView
    {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext);
        //...
    }

}
```

And in where you create a new `MyAdapter`, usually in your activity or fragment,
you have now something like `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter()`, instead change that to `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this)` if it is in your activity (since `Activity` is a type of `Context`) or `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext())` if it is in your fragment.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/why-fragments-and-when-to-use-fragments-instead-of-activities) if you don't know the difference of `Activity` and `Fragment`.

See [the inheritance hierarchy here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) if you don't know the relationship between `Activity` and `Context`.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Daniel , please can you more clarify it a little bit in code ?

Comment: it's in a ListView Adapter class

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Or is anything unclear?