# Activity vs Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am learning android from two resources one from video and one from book +(android developer resources ). Both show how to have multiple views in a different ways. Video one used activity and intent book used fragments. What is the best practice fragment/activity?When to use `Activity` and when to use `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely hear things like

> You can have an Activity without a Fragment but you cannot have a Fragment without Activity
>
> You can have multiple Fragments under a single Activity
>
> You can use Fragments to have multiple sections in a single screen
>
> Fragments has its own lifecycle

So I'd give my personal thought and a little bit of scenario based on my own experience on how I would decide which to use based on a given scenario.

Consider a `Registration Form` where I'm required to create 3 screen features of which contains `Basic Personal Info`, `Financial Information` and `Online Mailing Information`, in this case I would use multiple `Fragments` under 1 hosting `Activity` named `RegistrationActivity`.

Now consider same application where I'm required to create a `User Setting Screen` it wouldn't make sense if I create another `Fragment` under that same `Activity` right?, so that would be a separate `context` and everything about it will go to another `Activity` named `SettingsActivity`

There are more technical things under the hood, but most of the time you will decide which to use based on the use-case you are dealing with.

There is also an up to date architecture namely [Modular design](https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization) where each closely related components are grouped inside a module library, majority of such project will fall under the `feature` category where most of the time if not all,  have single `Activity` hosting multiple fragments. And going back to my scenario it would be like a `Registration Module`

Hope it make sense.

Have a look at another similar post
[Why fragments, and when to use fragments instead of activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/why-fragments-and-when-to-use-fragments-instead-of-activities)